# Порядковый номер элемента в двумерном массиве

Tags: c#, массивы

У меня есть двумерный массив [m,n] элементов. Как я могу узнать порядковый номер элемента в массиве? Индексация с нуля.

Пример: 
int[,] array = new int[3,2];
array[0,0] - нулевой элемент
array[0,1] - первый элемент
array[1,0] - второй элемент
array[1,1] - третий элемент
И так далее.

Comment: А вообще какая-то странная логика мне кажется, 1,1 это третий элемент. а 0,3 - какой и 3,1 какой и 2,2 какой будет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array[i,j]
порядковый номер i*n+j
```

Comment: а может быть i+j-1?

Comment: @user2455111 эмм. Проверьте вашу теорию для массива [4,4]. Последний элемент a[3,3] будет 15ым, а по вашей логике 5ым.

Comment: @user2455111 а элемент a[0,0] будет -1ым)

Comment: Да, да уже понял, что это же матрица, там плюсовать не получится

Answer (score 1):

`array[m,n]`, например `array(3,4)` (3 строки,4 колонки):

Порядковый номер элемента массива `=  (row-1) * n  + col`

если с ноля стартуешь сделай еще -1