# Работа с матрицами (двумерные массивы) С++

Tags: c++, массивы, динамические-массивы, матрицы

Помогите с кодом, пожалуйста

1. Умножение матриц разных размерностей (я явно попутал границы либо выделение памяти, не могу разобраться, иногда запускается (если вводить n < m), но перемножает неправильно).
2. Сортировать строки массива по возрастанию сумм четных элементов строк. (мой способ решения - завести дополнительный одномерный массив, в него записывать суммы, затем сортировкой (можно использовать любую) сортировать и тот и другой массивы сразу. Не работает).
3. Найти среди элементов первого столбца такой элемент, принадлежащий как можно большему количеству других столбцов (способ - создать второй массив, первая срока - столбец первой матрицы, вторая строка - подсчёт количества элементов в других столбцах, затем вывести элемент первой строки стоящий над максимальным элементом второй строки.Не работает. Возможно, можно использовать и одномерный массив, но я не догоняю как.)
4. Найти минимум среди сумм модулей элементов диагоналей параллельных побочной диагонали (функция из интернетов, некоторые моменты не понимаю как работают, тут не работает)

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cmath>
   #include <iomanip>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <ctime>
   #include <math.h>
   #include <stdio.h>


   void printimas(int** mas, const int n, const int m);
   void printdmas(double** mas, const int n, const int m);
   void genintmas(int** mas, const int n, const int m);
   void gendoubmas(double** mas, const int n, const int m);
   void umnmatrdialog(int** mas, int** tmp, int** tmp2, const int n, const int m);
   void umnmatr(int** mas, int** tmp, int** tmp2, const int n, const int m, int g);
   void bubsort(double** mas, double* mass, const int n, const int m);
   void sortchetelstr(double** mas, double* vect2, const int n, const int m);
   int minsumparpob(int** mas, const int n, const int m);
   void maxpovtvstolb(int** mas, const int n, const int m);

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
       srand(time(NULL));
       cout << "Введите размерность матрицы" << endl;
       int n, m, g;

       cin >> n;
       cout << "x" << endl;
       cin >> m;
       cout << endl;

       int** a = new int*[n];
       int** tmp = new int*[m];
       int** tmp2 = new int*[n];
       double** arr = new double*[n];
       double* vect2 = new double[n];

       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           a[i] = new int[m];
           // tmp2[i] = new int[m];
           arr[i] = new double[m];
       }

       genintmas(a, n, m);
       printimas(a, n, m);
       gendoubmas(arr, n, m);
       printdmas(arr, n, m);

       umnmatrdialog(a, tmp, tmp2, n, m);

       /*sortchetelstr(arr, vect2, n, m); //закомментил чтобы работать с умножением матриц, оно хотя бы запускается

       if (minsumparpob(a, n, m) == 1)
           cout << endl << "12345" << endl;
       if (minsumparpob(a, n, m) == 0)
           cout << endl << "Невозможно! Матрица не квадратная" << endl;

       maxpovtvstolb(a, n, m);
       */
       delete[] a;
       delete[] arr;
       return 0;
   }

   void genintmas(int** mas, const int n, const int m)
   { //работает нормально
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
               mas[i][j] = rand() % 201 - 100;
       }
   }
   void printimas(int** mas, const int n, const int m)
   { //работает нормально
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
           {
               cout << mas[i][j] << "\t";
           }
           cout << '\n';
       }
       cout << endl << endl;
   }
   void gendoubmas(double** mas, const int n, const int m)
   { //работает нормально
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
               mas[i][j] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX * (-101 - 100) + 100;
       }
   }
   void printdmas(double** mas, const int n, const int m)
   { //работает нормально
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
           {
               cout << fixed << setw(4) << mas[i][j] << "\t";
           }
           cout << '\n';
       }
       cout << endl << endl;
   }
   void umnmatr(int** mas, int** tmp, int** tmp2, const int n, const int m, int g)
   { // умножение матриц, вроде бы правильно
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
           {
               tmp2[i][j] = 0;
               for (int k = 0; k < g; k++)
                   tmp2[i][j] += mas[i][k] * tmp[k][j];
           }
       }
   }
   void umnmatrdialog(int** mas, int** tmp, int** tmp2, const int n, const int m) // задание 1
   {
       cout << endl
            << "\nУмножение матриц\nЧто выберете?\n1. Ввести вторую квадратную матрицу самому\n2. "
               "Сгенерировать "
               "вторую матрицу из случайных элементов"
            << endl;
       int z;
       int p = rand() % 10 + 2; //для случайной размерности матрицы
       cin >> z;
       if (z == 1) //ввод элементов второй матрицы в консоль вручную
       {
           cout << "Обратите внимание, чтобы количество строк вашей матрицы совпадало с количеством "
                   "столбцов существующей матрицы"
                << endl;
           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                   cin >> tmp[i][j];
           }
           umnmatr(mas, tmp, tmp2, n, m, p);
           cout << endl << endl << "Результат" << endl << endl;
           printimas(tmp2, n, m);
       }
       if (z == 2) // генерирование случайной второй матрицы
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
               tmp[i] = new int[p];
           for (int i = 0; i < p; i++)
               tmp2[i] = new int[n];

           genintmas(tmp, p, n);
           printimas(tmp, p, n);

           umnmatr(mas, tmp, tmp2, n, m, p);
           cout << endl << endl << "Результат" << endl << endl;
           printimas(tmp2, p, n);
       }
       else
       {
           cout << "Ошибка" << endl;
           system("pause");
       }
   }
   void sortchetelstr(double** mas, double* vect2, const int n, const int m) // задание 2
   {

       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < m; j = j + 2)
           {
               vect2[i] += mas[i][j];
           }

           bubsort(mas, vect2, n, m);

           printdmas(mas, n, m);
       }
   }
   void bubsort(double** mas, double* mass, const int n, const int m)
   {

       for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i)
       {
           for (int r = 0; r < n - i; r++)
           {
               if (mass[r] < mass[r + 1])
               {
                   // Обмен местами
                   double temp = mass[r];
                   mass[r] = mass[r + 1];
                   mass[r + 1] = temp;
                   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                   {
                       for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) //пытаюсь сортировать и второй массив тоже
                       {
                           double temp2 = mas[i][j];
                           mas[i][j] = mas[i][j + 1];
                           mas[i][j + 1] = temp2;
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   void maxpovtvstolb(int** mas, const int n, const int m) // задание 3
   {
       int** tmp = new int*[m]; //
       for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
           tmp[i] = new int[m];
       for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
       {
           for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
           {
               tmp[1][j] = mas[1][j];
               tmp[2][j] = 1;
           }
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
           {
               if (mas[i][j] == tmp[1][j])
                   tmp[2][j]++;
           }
       printimas(tmp, 2, m); //хотя бы просто вывести второй массив чтобы посмотреть правильно посчитал или нет
       //останется найти наибольшее число из второй строки и вывести вышестоящее
   }
   int minsumparpob(int** mas, const int n, const int m) // задание 4
   {
       int** tmp = new int*[m];
       int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           tmp[i] = new int[m];
       if (n != m)
           return 0;
       else
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < m - i; j++)
                   tmp[i][j] = mas[n - 1 - j][n - 1 - i];
           }
           for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
           {
               int sum = 0;
               for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
               {
                   if (mas[i][j] < 0)
                   {
                       sum = 0;
                       break;
                   }
                   else
                       sum += mas[i][j];
               }
               cout << "   " << sum;
               cout << "matrix y:"
                    << "\n";

               for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
               {
                   cout << "\n"
                        << "  ";
                   for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                   {
                       cout << tmp[i][j] << "    ";
                   }
               }
               cout << "\n"
                    << "\n";
               for (n = m; n > 0; n--)
               {
                   for (i = 0; i < m - 1; i++)
                   {
                       sum1 += mas[i][m - i - 2];
                       sum2 += tmp[i][m - i - 2];
                       m--;
                   }
               }
               if (sum1 < sum2)
                   min = sum1;
               else
                   min = sum2;

               cout << "up: " << sum1 << "   "
                    << "down: " << sum2 << "\n"
                    << "\n";
               cout << "min sum: " << abs(min);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: "Не работает" - напишите, что именно не работает, какие выдаются ошибки и какое требуется поведение. Экстрасенсы обитают не тут.

Comment: Умножение матриц крашится если вводишь, n>=m, если n<m, то несколько первых строк результата это числа похожие на результат умножения матриц, остальные - случайные числа из памяти.

Comment: Если что-то не работает - ставьте отладочный вывод перед тем, как что-то делать. В cout пишите значения параметров, какие элементы матрицы берете, что с ними делаете. Будет хотя бы с чем разбираться. Гадать по коду не принято

Comment: Чтобы побыстрее разобраться с памятью, посмотрите еще вот сюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/601489 Идея для вас была бы очень полезна, иначе вы приличное время потратите на разбор тонкостей работы new и delete, хотя это не имеет отношения к решению ваших задач

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В задании 3 используйте одномерный массив = столбец, индексом которого будет номер элемента, а значением - количество вхождений этого элемента в другие столбцы. Разумеется, значения при старте будут нулями.

Первым проходом по матрице вы найдете число вхождений каждого элемента и заполните одномерный массив (+1 в значение каждый раз, как находите то же значение, что и номер в одномерном массиве). Вторым проходом вы найдете максимальное значение в полученном одномерном массиве, его индекс - номер элемента первого столбца. Задача решена.

В коде ошибки, вам нужно еще раз внимательно посмотреть на него и обдумать. Используйте листок и карандаш, помогает 100%. 1-2 часа на обдумывание должно хватить.

В 4 задании выбросите функцию из интернета. Потом решите задачу на листочке самостоятельно для случая матрицы 3*3, 4*4 и 6*5. Когда у вас появится понимание - что же нужно сделать, напишите словами по пунктам, а что нужно сделать. После того как будет алгоритм в виде слов - написать код будет на порядок проще. 1-2 часа на решение примеров на листке, 1 час на алгоритм и около 1 часа на написание кода с отладкой.

Удачи.